# Sorting a text file based on data before the first comma

Tags: linux, unix, sorting

I have the following text file that contains rows in a format of [Number,IP address] and want to sort it based on the number portion. I tried using the command

```
sort -r -k 1 -t"," Input.txt > Output.txt
```

however I can't seem to figure out how to properly get the desired output. I'd appreciate any help!

Input File:

```
20,159.122.220.29
57,180,128.252.1
6749,182.100.67.59
3379,183.3.202.111
87,195.154.49.74
27,208.109.54.40
3085,218.25.208.92
142,41.223.57.47
```

Actual Output File:

```
87,195.154.49.74
6749,182.100.67.59
57,180,128.252.1
3379,183.3.202.111
3085,218.25.208.92
27,208.109.54.40
20,159.122.220.20
142,41.223.57.47
```

Desired Output File:

```
6749,182.100.67.59
3379,183.3.202.111
3085,218.25.208.92
142,41.223.57.47
87,195.154.49.74
57,180,128.252.1
27,208.109.54.40
20,159.122.220.20
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `-g` flag to sort using general numerical rather than ASCII.

```
sort -r -g -k 1 -t"," Input.txt
```

`-n` or `-h` would also work depending on the types of numbers in that first field.  See `man sort` for details.

Comment: Two notes: (1) `-n` is specified by POSIX, `-g` and `-h` are not. In such cases I prefer advising the most portable option (here: `-n`) before non-portable alternatives. To be clear: this is *my preference*, not a rule. (2) It's not "rather than ASCII" but "rather than what your locale (`LC_COLLATE`) specifies". // Nevertheless this is a decent first answer, should be enough to solve the problem. +1 from me.